# CSS Styling in GTK+

Tags: css, gtk, gtk3

Ok, i recently started programming with GTK+ in C.
I have a GdkToggleButton in my code and i want to add styling to it with css.
I've read almost all of GTK3+ documentation here https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable but found nothing that fits my case.
Actually there is a part of the documentation about CSS but i couldn't find the part to actually parse the css file.

**All I want to do is to change color of a GdkToggleButton either with CSS or any other method.**

I want to know where to put the css file and how to parse it and add it to a Widget.

I actually could get GdkRGBA (color) of a button but changes have no effect.
Here's how i change GdkRGBA of button.

```
GdkRGBA *color ;
GtkWidget *button;
GtkStyleContext *context;

color = gdk_rgba_copy (color); // I don't know to initialize GdkRGBA :(

context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(button);    
button = gtk_toggle_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");
gtk_style_context_get_color(context,
                            GTK_STATE_FLAG_NORMAL,
                            color);
gdk_rgba_parse(color,
                "red");
```

***SOLVED***

```
gtk_css_provider_load_from_path (cssProvider,
                                    "/home/shadow_m2/code.css",
                                    NULL);
gtk_style_context_add_provider (context,
                                    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(cssProvider),
                                    GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER); // I had used wrong priority on first try
gtk_style_context_save (context);
```

Comment: You are looking for GtkCssProvider.

Comment: I also tried that and it loads a css file but don't know how to style a widget with GtkCssProvider. @andlabs

Comment: You can load CSS from memory with GtkCssProvider. For applying it to a widget, see GtkStyleContext (which all GtkWidgets have).

Comment: Is there any other way to change color of a button ? @andlabs

Comment: @andlabs Yes. It worked with GtkCssProvider.I'll add the solution to my qustion now.Please make your comment an "answer" and I'll accept it.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load custom CSS embedded in your program with `gtk_css_provider_load_from_data()`. GtkCssProvider is how to load CSS in general.

Then you get the GtkWidget's style context and call `add_provider()` on it. Use the `APPLICATION` priority; that's what you're adding anyway (application-specific CSS).

Also the `save()` call is not necessary.

Comment: yes my problem was in priority i had used. Thank you