# Problems with GtkCssProvider and CSS styles

Tags: css, gtk3

I'm developing simple program using GTK3 and trying to use GtkCssProvider to set CSS styles for particular widgets (fragment):

```
text = gtk_text_view_new();
provider = gtk_css_provider_new();
gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(provider,
                                    "textview {"
                                    "  font-family: serif;"
                                    "  font-size: 30px;"
                                    "  margin-top: 10px;"
                                    "  margin-bottom: 10px;"
                                    "  color: green;"
                                    "}",-1, NULL);
context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(text);
gtk_style_context_add_provider(context,
                                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider),
                                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
```

Font properties are set right way, but margins and color not. I haven't got any CSS parsing errors. If i use g_object_set() function to set e.g. margins, everything works fine:

```
g_object_set(text, "margin-top", 10, NULL);
g_object_set(text, "margin-bottom", 10, NULL);
```

Any ideas, what is wrong? Something with CSS? Maybe there is better approach to play with GtkTextView properties (text and widget colors)? I also tried GtkInspector tool and direct CSS editing, but this also does't work regarding margins and colors.

Comment: Try taking away the `px` from `margin-top: 10px`, and see if the margin gets applied. (You didn't add `px` in `g_object_set(text, "margin-top", 10, NULL);` !)

Comment: Probably not best idea, got parsing problems (and the same effect no margins):
Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:59: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.
Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: <data>:1:77: Not using units is deprecated. Assuming 'px'.

Comment: What is your Gtk version ?

Comment: 3.22.30 (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Comment: Could you give me a Minimal Reproducible _Compileable_ Example, so that I can test it on my machine (Gtk 30.24, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Comment: As you can read in the [gtk docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.22/chap-css-properties.html#id-1.5.3.3.29), all `margin-` properties should be supported ... Could you try to delete the margin properties from your css, and add `margin: 100px !important` ? (If there is a waring, delete the `!important`)

Comment: I also noticed that the color of the text in the text view does not become green when using the css provider. Is that the same with you ?

Comment: I think I found the solution : try adding `gtk_style_context_save (context);` after adding the css provider (`gtk_style_context_add_provider(...)`) (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40248299/css-styling-in-gtk))

Comment: Unfortunately, still doesn't work for me. It seems that this is kind of missing functionality/error in GTK?

Comment: No, in the gtk docs is stated that `margin` is supported for your gtk version. If this does not work, I have no other idea than to post a question on discourse.gome.org. I will do this for you (I already have an account there), and send you a link to the thread !

Comment: Here is the link to the topic on Gnome discourse : https://discourse.gnome.org/t/gtk-3-22-textview-not-showing-margin-and-font-color/5903

Comment: Sorry for the late response, yesterday I completely forgot about you and was reminded just now when reading my mails, I think I found a solution now,

Answer (score 0):

Minimal compileable example showing problem (to see margins uncomment lines 57-60). Compiled with gcc 7.5.0.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static GtkWidget *window;
static GtkWidget* layoutGrid;
static GtkWidget* textLog;
static GtkTextBuffer* bufferLog;
static GtkCssProvider* cssProviderLog;
static GtkStyleContext* context;

gboolean wndDeleteEventHandler(__attribute__((unused)) GtkWidget* widget,
                                __attribute__((unused)) GdkEvent* event,
                                __attribute__((unused)) gpointer user_data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
    
    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    gtk_init(&argc , &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 640, 480);
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
    g_signal_connect(window, "delete-event", G_CALLBACK(wndDeleteEventHandler), NULL);

    layoutGrid = gtk_grid_new();
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(layoutGrid, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(layoutGrid, TRUE);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), layoutGrid);

    textLog = gtk_text_view_new();
    gtk_widget_set_name(textLog, "textlog");
    bufferLog = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW (textLog));
    cssProviderLog = gtk_css_provider_new();
    gtk_css_provider_load_from_data(cssProviderLog,
                                    "textview {"
                                    "font-family: serif;"
                                    "font-size: 30px;"
                                    "margin-top: 10px;"
                                    "margin-bottom: 10px;"
                                    "color: green;"
                                    "}",-1, NULL);
    context = gtk_widget_get_style_context(textLog);
    gtk_style_context_add_provider(context,
                                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(cssProviderLog),
                                GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(bufferLog, "Hello, this is some text in log buffer", -1);
    gtk_widget_set_hexpand(textLog, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(textLog, TRUE);
    // g_object_set(textLog, "margin-left", 20, NULL);
    // g_object_set(textLog, "margin-top", 20, NULL);
    // g_object_set(textLog, "margin-bottom", 20, NULL);
    // g_object_set(textLog, "margin-right", 20, NULL);
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(layoutGrid), textLog, 0, 0, 1, 1);

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);
    gtk_main();
}
```

Makefile

```
C = gcc
CFLAGS = -c

OBJ = \
    screen.o

.c.o:
    $(C) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` $<

all: $(OBJ)
    $(C) -o test $(OBJ) `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

Comment: Okay, I have both Gtk 3.22 and Gtk 3.24 on my machine, and with both versions it's the same : no margins with css provider, margins present with `gtk_object_set` ...

Answer (score 0):

According to the list of CSS nodes in the [GtkTextview docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html#id-1.3.11.8.12.3), it seems you have to apply the margins on the border subnodes and the font should be applied to the text subnode, so your CSS might look like this:

```css
textview border.top {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

textview border.bottom {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

texview text {
    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: green;
}
```

Please let me know if this fixes your issue !

Comment: Thanks for commitment so far! Unfortunatelly, above statements still doesn't work for me. Are you aware about GTK3 set of examples i could check regarding using CSS?

Comment: @Robert I got the code to set the font size, family and color and am currently working at applying the margis, too ...

Comment: @Robert no, I couldn't find any examples on how to style Gtk widgets with CSS

Comment: @Robert I finally got an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66824664/css-margins-not-being-applied-to-a-gtk-textview/66862723?noredirect=1#comment118224801_66862723), and it is _not_ possible to set margins on a `GtkTextView` from CSS. You  can only set them by using the `.set_margin*` functions from code. But maybe you could set the margins from CSS on your `GtkGrid`, as it is a `GtkContainer` like a `GtkVBox` ...