# CSS margins not being applied to a Gtk textview

Tags: css, python-3.x, css-selectors, gtk, margins

I have the following minimal reproducible example code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
#-*-coding: utf-8-*-

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("destroy", lambda _: Gtk.main_quit())
box = Gtk.VBox()
win.add(box)
view = Gtk.TextView()
buf = view.get_buffer()
buf.set_text("Hello, this is some text !")
prov = Gtk.CssProvider.new()
prov.load_from_data("""
text {
    color: red;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 30px;
}
""".encode())
ctx = win.get_style_context()
ctx.add_provider_for_screen(Gdk.Screen.get_default(), prov, 800)
box.add(view)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

The font and background gets colored, but the margins are not applied. Why,  and what would fix it ?

Note : When I apply the margins to the box with following CSS

```css
text {
    color: red;
    background-color: yellow;
}
box {
    margin: 30px;
}
```

or add
`python
view.set("margin-left", 10)
view.set("margin_right, 10)
...

```
the margins are applied. So the cause must be a wrong selector ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not css nodes to margins in textview. You need to use functions like `set_left_margin(left_margin)` `set_right_margin(right_margin)` or `set_justification(justification)`.

usage

```
Gtk.TextView().set_left_margin(10) /*value is in pixels*/
```

CSS nodes

```
textview.view
├── border.top
├── border.left
├── text
│   ╰── [selection]
├── border.right
├── border.bottom
╰── [window.popup]
```

css nodes only appears in c docs [c documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html)

this is the py documentation [py documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtktextview.html#method-gtktextview--set-left-margin)

Comment: 1. Could you provide a source for that ? 2. I think that's weird, because, `GtkWidget` supports CSS margins, and `GtkTextView` inherits from  `GtkWiget`, so the support must be switched off explicitly in `GtkTextView`'s source code. 3. How exactly does `set_left_margin` & co. work, and whats the difference to setting it from the CSS ?

Comment: In textview margins are properties, it can be modified with functions; with css you can only modify css nodes. Try `Gtk.TextView().set_left_margin(10)` https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtktextview.html#method-gtktextview--set-left-margin

Comment: I knew already about `Gtk.TextView.set_left_margin(10)`, my question was if it is possible from the CSS. I conclude from your answer and comment that it's not. Is that right ?

Comment: It is not possible from css